# How to create .aar file with Embeddinator-4000

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, embeddinator

I have a simple Android application wrote in c# and Xamarin. My purpose is to import this project into Android native application. I saw that Embeddinator-4000 can do the work and I installed it via Nuget, but unfortunately I can't find how to export an .aar file. 
In project properties ->Build Events->Post Build Event command line I put this command: 
 **set OUTPUT="$(SolutionDir)output"
 if exist %OUTPUT% rmdir /S /Q %OUTPUT%
"$(SolutionDir)packages\Embeddinator-4000.0.3.0\tools\Embeddinator-4000.exe" "$(TargetPath)" --gen=Java --platform=Android --outdir=%OUTPUT% -c**

After build I get the error:"The command exited with code 3"
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> After build I get the error:"The command exited with code 3"

As listed in this [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx), code 3 means the system cannot find the path specified.

Please check your path in the command.